# Scrapy "next page" implemenation error

Tags: scrapy

My goal:

1. Scrap all product links on start_url
2. Send product link to parse_items, scrap product details, save in json
3. Find the next page link from start_url
4. Repeat and rinse, until reach the end of catalog

[image: Process]

So far, I've tried two method, but neither works. Can anyone point me to the right direction?

(1) Use LinkExtractor to get all the item links, likely error: the next link is excluded, therefore no next_page_url

```
class urllink(CrawlSpider):
        name = "urllink"

        allowed_domains = ['url.com'] 

        start_urls = [
            'http://www.url.com/',
            ]

        rules = [
            Rule(
                LinkExtractor(
                    allow = ('items/detail/-/id='),
                    deny = (),
                    canonicalize=True,
                    unique=True
                ),
                follow=False,
                callback="parse_items"
            )
        ]

        def parse_items(self, response):

            yield {
                'title':response.css("cite::text").extract_first(),
                    }

            next_page_url = response.css('.next a::attr(href)').extract_first()
            if next_page_url is not None:
                yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_page_url))
```

(2) Calling next_page_url in the main page scrap, send the item link to item scrap. But something is wrong, not sure where.

```
class urlcom(CrawlSpider):
    name = "urlcom3"

    allowed_domains = ['url.com'] 

    start_urls = [
        'http://www.url.com',
        ]

    def parse_links(self, response):
        links = response.css('ul[class = "cmn-list-product01"] a::attr(href)').extract()
        for link in links:
            print(link)
            scrapy.Request(link, call_back = "parse_items")

        next_page_url = response.css('.next a::attr(href)').extract_first()
        if next_page_url is not None:
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_page_url))

    def parse_items(self, content):

        yield {
            'title':content.css("cite::text").extract_first(),
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally solved this issue myself, turned out it was small mistakes. If anyone faces similar problem, here's the mistakes which I made.

I picked 2nd code as the base.

1) Scrapy's first spider must be named "parse"

> def parse(self, response):

2) Use yield and callback to get pass the link into 2nd item spider

> yield scrapy.Request(link, callback = self.parse_items)

Hope this helps.